# can i change the default voices from FLite?

Tags: iphone, text-to-speech, flite

i am working on tts application it needs to convert text into different voices like Male ,Female and childs voice i had tried some how but it's not working,

```
[fliteEngine setVoice:@"cmu_us_kal16"];
[fliteEngine setPitch:300.0 variance:1.1 speed:1.5];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is voice folder in flite tts ..you can select any voice from there and set in
`[fliteEngine setVoice:@"cmu_us_kal16"]`;

Comment: i had found dvoice for male and female, what would be the best voice for a child ??

Comment: Depends on you.  Think female voice

Comment: Also, I want to set the duration stretch.  How can I set that?

Comment: And... where is this?  Is it in a file?